# Why does DOMContentLoaded behave different in safari then in other browsers

Tags: javascript, safari, domcontentloaded

Why does `DOMContentLoaded` behave different in Safari (10.1) then in other browsers (Chrome/Firefox) and what is the best workaround? For now I use a `setTimeout` as a workaround but that results in the undesirable effect of a jumpy behavior in other browsers...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    setTimeout(fn,0)
}, false);
```

Comment: `behave different in Safari` in what way do you claim it is different? - and, Safari is the new Internet Exploder as far as following "specs" :p

Comment: The event is executed in a later stadium in Safari than it does for Firefox or Chrome. When the function `fn`, will log the value of the *innerWidth* of a *domElement*. It will be log 0 in Safari, and `x` in Chrome or Firefox. When I don't use the setTimeout hack. (Where `x` would be the actual Number value)